# The set $\{\frac{1}{x^2-3}: x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is bounded? Explain.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, rational-numbers

> The set $\{\frac{1}{x^2-3}: x\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is bounded? Explain.

I got this question some weeks ago in an **Introduction to Real Analysis** exam. In the exam review, the professor mentioned it could be solved with *supremum and infimum* concepts. Indeed, the exam (technically) was related to sequences (so when I saw this question I thought it could be approached with sequences techniques).

However, I didn't progress so much. This is my approach:

By hyphotesis we know $x\in \mathbb{Q}\implies x=\frac{p}{q}$, where $ q\neq 0$. Considering some bounds, we have:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-3}<\frac{1}{x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x} \implies \frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2-3}<\frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^2}\leq \frac{1}{\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)}$$
So, we have $\sup \left(\frac{1}{x^2-3}\right)= \frac{1}{x}$. $\therefore$ The sequence is bounded $\forall x\in\mathbb{Q}$.

I know my approach is a little bit... bad. I got a 2/20 score in this question, because if $x\in (0,1)$ then the bounds are not true and is not true $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q}$.

What could be a good procedure to solve this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, $\sqrt{3}$ is not a rational. However the rationals are a dense subset of the reals. What does that imply for the $sup$ of that set?

Comment: jcg: Yeah! I have updated the last statement. It was one correction made by my prof. It does not work with $x\in(0,1)$ in fact. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems.

1. $1/(x^2 - 3) < 1/x^2$ does not hold for $x > \sqrt{3}$. Moreover, the RHS is undefined when $x = 0$.
2. $1/x^2 < 1/x$ does not hold for $x \in (0,1)$, as you mentioned. Moreover, the RHS is undefined when $x = 0$.
3. Even if $1/(x^2 - 3) < 1/x$ was true, this would not show that $\{ 1/(x^2 - 3) : x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ was bounded. This might be a problem with your understanding of the word "bounded"? A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be bounded if there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq s \leq b$ for all $s \in S$. You simply did not produce such constants, so your proof stood no chance of being correct.

In fact, the set in question is *not* bounded. You should try to prove this by producing a sequence $x_1, x_2, \dots$ of rational numbers such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2 - 3} = \infty$.

Let me extract a couple morals from this story:

1. Make sure you justify every claim you make: you could have caught errors #1 and #2 if you had done so.
2. Before you start writing a proof, spell out to yourself *exactly* what you need to show. In this case, you should say to yourself "I need to produce real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \leq \frac{1}{x^2 - 3} \leq b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, or show that no such $a, b$ exist". This has two advantages: first, understanding what you need to show often helps you figure out how to approach a proof, and second, if you know exactly what you need to show, you'll never end a proof without deriving the correct conclusion (this was error #3).

Edit: Missed that the first inequality also fails, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* [Heron's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) starting at $x_0=1$ produces a sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt3$.